# Remove entity with relationships

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have next entities. `Car` has ManyToMany relationship with `Human`. I am using auxiliary class **Assign** between **Car** and **User**

```
@Entity
public class Car implements Serializable
{
   //...

   @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.TRUE)
   @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "car")
   private Set<Assign> cars = new HashSet<Assign>();
   //...
}  

@Entity
class Assign implements Serializable 
{
   //...

   @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "HUMAN_CAR", nullable = false)
   private Human human;

   @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "CAR_HUMAN", nullable = false)
   private Car car;
   //..

}  

@Entity
public class Human implements Serializable
{
    //...

   @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.TRUE)
   @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "human")
   private Set<Assign> cars = new HashSet<Assign>();  
   // ...  
}
```

Now I try to remove car inside container managed transaction

```
   public void deleteCar(final long id)
   {      
      final Car car = entityManager.find(roleId, Car.class);
      entityManager.remove(car);  
   }
```

but I get

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: deleted entity passed to persist: [com.dto.Assign#<null>]
```

Comment: Maybe you have to remove all `Assign`-s before you remove `Car`.

Comment: @GaborSch But I have `CascadeType.ALL`. I think Hibernate should remove them

Comment: Why do you use the `Assign` entity at all? You could use a `ManyToMany` relation instead. Or are there additional fields in `Assign` entity?

Comment: @home I can't, assign table contains some another fields

Comment: Have you tried removing `Assign`-s?

Comment: Did the solution help? Does it work now?

Comment: @GaborSch no, I still get exeption...

Answer (score 1):

Before remove `car`, you need first remove `car` from `Assign`.

There is another design problem here. You have `CascadeType.ALL` on `cars` in `Car` entity, which means Car and its assigns has a composition relationship(not simply aggregation/association relationship). On the other hand, same relationship exists between Human and its assigns. Obviously assigned `cars` could be shared between a car and a human, but composition relationship follows non-shared semantics. Suppose one deletes a car and cascade delete its assigns, those shared in `person` side will become orphans.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `Assign`-s before you remove the `Car`

```
public void deleteCar(final long id)
{      
  final Car car = entityManager.find(roleId, Car.class);
  for(Assign assign : car.getAssigns()) {
     entityManager.remove(assign);
  }
  entityManager.remove(car);  
}
```

Your getter may be differently named, I can't see that code.